# Punctuation in a sentence "from A or B to C and even D"

Tags: punctuation, commas, sentence-patterns

Is there a need for punctuation in the following sentence: "Response time has reduced from weeks or days to hours and even minutes in some cases."

More generally, how should one use punctuation in a family of sentences:

" ..... from A or B to C and even D ....."?

Answer (score 2):

Technically no punctuation is necessary, but it might be helpful to add a few commas and parentheses:

> Response time has reduced, from weeks or days, to hours (and even minutes in some cases).

Answer (score 2):

How about separating the from ideas from the to ideas. Then treat the add-on idea with long dashes. (I've grown to love the long dashes, revealed to me by an editor long ago...)

As in, "Response time has reduced from weeks or days, to hours — and even minutes — in some cases."

In the second sub query, " ... from A or B to C and even D ...", it would follow as "...from A or B, to C — and even D."

The sense of each ends with "to hours" or "to C" as the capper of the idea, then an afterthought chimes in, hence the long dash.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Buzz Mega that an "em" dash might help.  In addition, it may allow you to remove the last "and" to make the last, and presumably the most important, clause stronger.

> Response time has reduced from weeks or days to hours—even minutes in some cases.

The punctuation depends on what part of the sentence you want to place the emphasis.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not always correct, so correct me if I am wrong. I think the correct punctuation would be "Response time has reduced from weeks and days to hours and even minutes on occasion."

Very good question.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on whether you pause or not when you say the sentence because essentially a comma is used to indicate a pause.